# Pass a non-bound input value to arraycontroller via an action in ember

Tags: ember.js

I'm rendering a iterative template that contains an input field and an action to my array controller, I can happily pass the current model but I'm a loss as to how to pass the unbound input value contents.

To give a totally simple example, think of a list of products template on an ecomms site, with a qty field and update button.

```
{{#each product in controller}}
   {{product.name}}
   <input name="qty" placeholder="Qty" />
   <button {{action addToCart product}} ></button>  
{{/each}}
```

This is a simple product list, not a view cart contents list so the qty field has no business being a part of the product model. I need qty to remain unbound (always loading blank)

How can I pass the value of the qty field to the addToCart action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the quantity should not be bound to the model, but it should be bound to either a controller/component.

I recommend extracting a component and doing something like follows:

```
{{#each product in controller}}
   {{product-component product=product}}
{{/each}}
```

In `app/components/product-component.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    quantity:0,
    actions: {
        addToCart: function (product, qty) {
            console.log(product.get('name') + ' ' + qty);
        }
    }
});
```

In `app/templates/components/product-component.hbs`:

```
   {{product.name}}
   {{input value=quantity name="qty" placeholder="Qty"}}
   <button {{action addToCart product quantity}} ></button>
```

Notice that we have passed the model in as `product` but we are binding to `quantity` which is not a property of `product`.

Comment: Total legend! Components were the answer. Slightly out of the scope of my question but it might be worth providing the component backing code to give a full solution for noobs to components like myself http://pastebin.com/r3XfNWpX (I changed product-component to product-list to avoid ProductComponentComponent)

Comment: I updated the answer to include the component definition with the assumption that the user is utilizing ember-cli. I see you are using the global variables, but since the community advocates using ember-cli and [ES6 exports](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html) I felt that was more useful.